# how to set x and y coordinates in image manipulation.

Tags: php, image-processing, image-manipulation

i just do image watermarking in php it's working but not setting image like i want,here's my code of php file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// Give the Complete Path of the folder where you want to save the image    
$folder="uploads/";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], "$folder".$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$file='uploads/'.$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];

$uploadimage=$folder.$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
$newname=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];

// Set the thumbnail name
$thumbnail = $folder.$newname."_thumbnail.jpg"; 
$actual = $folder.$newname.".jpg";
$imgname=$newname."_thumbnail.jpg";

// Load the mian image
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadimage);

// load the image you want to you want to be watermarked
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng('uploads/logo1.png');

// get the width and height of the watermark image
$water_width = imagesx($watermark);
$water_height = imagesy($watermark);

// get the width and height of the main image image
$main_width = imagesx($source);
$main_height = imagesy($source);

// Set the dimension of the area you want to place your watermark we use 0
// from x-axis and 0 from y-axis 
$dime_x = 0;
$dime_y = 0;

// copy both the images
imagecopy($source, $watermark, $dime_x, $dime_y, 0, 0, $water_width, $water_height);

// Final processing Creating The Image
imagejpeg($source, $thumbnail, 100);
}
?>
<img src='uploads/<?php echo $imgname;?>'>
</body>
</html>
```

and my html code also working fine.but problem with generated image it's like that
[image]

text with 'JACLIN ADMIN' is my png image and i want to apply it in middle from up and left. i just put 0 for both but problem is how can i put it in middle dynamicaly when size of images with diffrent height and width?please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to find the middle point of your image:

```
$im_middle_w = $main_width/2;
$im_middle_h = $main_height/2;
```

Then you just need to add the watermark there but you need to move the watermark to the left by half (so it's actually centered):

```
$dime_x = $im_middle_w - $water_width/2;
$dime_y = $im_middle_h - $water_height/2;
```

Haven't tested it but it should work. If it doesn't work, feel free to link the images and I'll see to the code myself.

Answer (score 0):

First set Value:

$watermark_pos_x = (imagesx($image)/2) - (imagesx($watermark)/2) - 15;  $watermark_pos_y = (imagesy($image)/2) - (imagesy($watermark)/2) - 10;

Then after apply value on Function:

// merge the source image and the watermark

imagecopy($image, $watermark,  $watermark_pos_x, $watermark_pos_y, 0, 0, imagesx($watermark), imagesy($watermark));